# How to use Mozilla Network Security Services(NSS) in VS2015

Tags: c++, firefox, visual-studio-2015, nss

I want use functions from [Mozilla Network Security Services](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/), but I didn't find how to work with them from *Visual Studio 2015*.

I downloaded it [from here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/security/nss/releases/NSS_3_9_RTM/src/), but I get an error when I try to build it:

> Not found 'types.h'

(I searched for the file in the project folder and it does not exist)

How to can use NSS in VS2015?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the location of the library's header files into your project properties. You probably also need to specify the directory where the library's `.lib` files are, in case it uses precompiled libs.

Right-click the project, select *Properties* and enter the path to the library's header directory here:

[image: VS 2015 Properties - VC++ Directories]

Comment: Thanks, I added the directories, I have not the _.lib _ Where I can download precompiled **NSS**

Comment: If NSS comes without them, you probably won't need any. Follow the instructions given by the NSS developers.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I tried but not work -> Not found 'types.h'.

Comment: Ah, this isn't even an NSS header. This is the C header `sys/types.h` which is shipped with Visual Studio. You need to specify the path to it. Locate it on your system and tell the compiler to use it.

Comment: I fixed the problem commented the line, but now a new error _CERT_some_functions unresolved_ when I try to build it.